# Why doesn't the Blender console go away when opening the program?

Tags: command-line

I started having an issue a few days ago with Blender. When starting up the program it runs the console and it never goes away, it stays like the image. I can still use the program, but i don't know why this is happening. Any solution?
[image: Image of the console]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The previous answer to this question did not work for me, but this does.

Go into  Windows settings > Privacy & Security > For Developers > Terminal
and in the drop down menu change from "Let Windows decide" to "Windows Console Host"

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! It solved my issue

Comment: Thanks, solved! I use the new Windows Terminal, and this setting can also be changed in-app: `Settings` -> `Startup` -> `Default terminal application` -> `Windows Console Host` -> `Save`. Blender console now disappears after `blender.exe` launch is complete!

Answer (score 8):

Same here, since a few days – due to a Windows 11 update, I think.

Anyway, to start Blender without the console, you can run `blender-launcher.exe`. It's in the same directory as your `blender.exe`.

Comment: Thankls a lot! That worked

Comment: Don't forget to click the ✅ next to that post to mark it as the right answer to your question.

Comment: This is awesome to know, thanks! The only downside: if you want to keep Blender pinned to your taskbar, you'll have to pin `blender-launcher.exe` which will result in a duplicate blender icon once Blender is launched and running.